# Preloader Screen Using HTML CSS & JQuery Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Preloader Screen Using HTML CSS & JQuery Not Working
I wanted to add a preloader on my website.
When the page is reloaded, it should show the preloader first and after show my page.
Butm it does not stop showing me the preload icon.
I used people's guides and for them it works properly but do not know why for me it does not work properly
I have attached my full code

```css
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
#loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #A0816C;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#loader:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #A0816C;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
#loader:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #A0816C;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Black Bakery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  </head>

  <body>
    

    <div id="preloader">
      <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <H1 style="color:red;">MORRR</H1>

    <script>
        $(window).on("load",function(){
          $(".preloader").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    </script>
 


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(".preloader")` is wrong... you need to get the id: `$("#preloader")`

Comment: Hi @MorBiton, it's often useful to open your browser's dev tools and check in the console that there are no errors - this one would probably have been picked up - such mistakes are easily made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the JQuery

```
    <script>
        $(window).on("load",function(){
          $(".preloader").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    </script>
```

**$(".preloader")** means select the class `preloader`, but you wand to select the emelent of `id=preloader` so you should use **$("#preloader")**

Therefroe, modify the jquery code to:

```
    <script>
        $(window).on("load",function(){
          $("#preloader").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    </script>
```